# Custard Filled Donut

Tags: custard, doughnuts

If I purchased a fresh custard filled Boston Cream donut on Saturday and left it at room temperature is it still ok to eat on Monday?

Comment: Dennis, welcome. We can’t possibly say whether it’s spoiled or not. But we can tell you about the food safety side and there the verdict is clear: “not safe”

Comment: @Stephie : but only because it had custard in it.  Other types of donuts are much lower risk.  (otherwise, there'd be an issue with storing them in display cases for hours at a time)

Comment: @Joe exactly. I would still have sent the user to the canonical question, but with a different comment.